# How to increase number of workers in Daphne with Django

Tags: django, daphne

With gunicorn I can increase thenumber of workers using -w 17

```
command: gunicorn server.asgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 17 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

How can I do that with daphne to utilize the CPU available?

```
command: daphne server.asgi:application --port 8000 --bind 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Daphne does not offer the possibility to increase the number of workers, but you can use [supervisor](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor) with Daphne to configure the number of processes.