# How to divide Daphne requests on mutiple processors?

Tags: django, server, daphne, asgi

I use a Daphne server for my ASGI Django application. When I run htop on my Ubuntu server it shows all the load on only one processor and the app gets slow, so I'd like to know what is the easiest way to speed up my server. App is inside a Docker container.

I run Daphne with `command: daphne WBT.asgi:application --bind "0.0.0.0" --port "8000"`.
I use Nginx as a proxy.

I tried using uvicorn server with multiple workers but then I get problems with layout. Ie. let's say that I have 4 workers when I visit my web app, it loads it on only one worker correctly, so in 25% cases I get no layout.

Comment: [Does this answer you question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72016672/8237838)

Comment: @May.D I don't know if it can help me. I'm a noob, so I don't even know how Supervisor should be used.

Comment: Have a look to this example from channels doc : https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#nginx-supervisor-ubuntu

Comment: @May.D Ok, now I have additional questions because I don't understand anything. :'( 
1. How does supervisor work?
2. My django app runs in Docker container on my mini-server because I have other python things with different requirements that make conflict if I run app outside of container. How to deploy app with supervisord inside a container.
3. Theoretically I could use uvicorn instead of Daphne but then I have a problem with layout. I'll paste link to the pictures later.

Comment: @May.D I did it. I made it with supervisor inside of docker container. It was bloody. If someone needs help, reach me in comments. :DDD